# iOS - Initializing UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In my app I have a `UIViewController` and a `UIView` named

- HomeViewController
- HomeView

They are both being loaded from a nib and the nib files are named the same as the class names
When I try to initialize my ViewController:

```
HomeViewController *h = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
```

It tries to load the viewController using the nib file for my UIView instead of the nib for my ViewController, If i load using `initWithNibNamed` it works fine.

Is this a bug in iOS I have never had this problem before. I am running against iOS 5 beta 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the way that you are naming your view and viewcontroller which is causing the problem. From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (look at the nibName property)

> 1. If the view controller class name ends with the word “Controller”, as
>    in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the
>    class name without the word “Controller”, as in MyView.nib.
> 2. It looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller
>    class. For example, if the class name is MyViewController, it looks
>    for a MyViewController.nib file.

If you changed the HomeView to MyHomeView for example, your code will start working again. BUT using initWithNibName: method is the recommended way for initializing a ViewController